# Convert a stream to Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I need to collect all the data from the stream and resolve it as promise.

I created this stream:

```
class CollectToPromise extends Writable {
  constructor(options) {
    super();
    this._result = ""

    this.result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.on('finish', resolve):w
      this.on('error', reject)
    }).then(() => this._result)

  }

  _write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    this._result += chunk
    callback()
  }

  _writev(chunks, callback) {
    chunks.forEach(c => {
      this._result += chunk
    })
    callback()
  }

  asPromise() {
    return this.result
  }
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
var r = fs.createReadStream('secrets');
const c = new CollectToPromise()
const encrypt = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password);
r.pipe(encrypt).pipe(c).asPromise().then((res) => console.log(res)
```

My questions are:

1. What do you think about the solution, including the naming?
2. How can I avoid the warning: `(node:32386) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr`?

Comment: `asPromise` can be problematic depending on how you implement it. If you create the promise before `asPromise` is called, and if you reject that Promise due to an error occuring in th stream, then you can get a unhandled promise rejection warning  if your code does not use `.asPromise` at all, and that waring will result in a real error in future that will exit the application.

Comment: >then you can get a unhandled promise rejection warning if your code does not use 
it's probably a downside of using any promise

Comment: Tha naming `asPromise` implies that this Promise is created on demand when `asPromise` is called. And not that it already exist before that call. So writing only `r.pipe(encrypt).pipe(c);` should at least not result in a unhandled promise rejection warning. Just because it would break the expectation.

Comment: Ok, now I see your point, thx

Comment: Missing closing parenthesis `)` at `.then()`.  Why is second parameter to `.then()` or `.catch()` not used to handle error? Does the code at the question return the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand why you are attempting to extend `Writable` here.

At the end of the day, it seems as if your pipeline is what you are REALLY wanting to have a promise interface.

Luckily this is really easy to do with recent versions of node using `Stream.pipeline` and `Util.promisify()`.  There is an even an example in the [Stream.pipeline documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html)

Comment: Why do I need it? for example testing - it's quite handy to have a result is promise for testing.
 Stream.pipeline  - I don't have a 'collected' result with it